# JavaScript RegEx to replace words starting with # in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I am using the below function to replace words beginig with # from the string, with variables of exact same name from the extra_data object.

```
var messageString = "The folder #folder_name was removed from the workspace #workspace_name by #user_name"
var re = /(?:^|\W)#(\w+)(?!\w)/g, match;
while (match = re.exec(messageString)) {
  messageString = messageString.replace(match[0],extra_data[match[1]]);
  console.log("I am here--------------------------------------------->1");
  console.log(messageString);
}
```

Console log

```
I am here--------------------------------------------->1
The folder23545 was removed from the workspace #workspace_name by #user_name
I am here--------------------------------------------->1
The folder23545 was removed from the workspace127 by #user_name
```

The above code replaces only 2 instances and sometimes eats up white space also as you can see at workspace127.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What is the point of that lookahead?

Comment: Just use thg435's solution. It makes the most sense to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess `replace` will be more suitable here:

```
result = messageString.replace(/#(\w+)/g, function(_, $1) { return extra_data[$1] })
```

or, to replace only words that start with `#`:

```
.replace(/(^|\W)#(\w+)/g, function(_, $1, $2) { return $1 + extra_data[$2] })
```

Comment: I probably would have a check to make sure that there is a value. +1

Answer (score 1):

- You are changing the string inside the loop. `re.exec` uses a `lastIndex` attribute to store where to start the next match. When you replace "#workspace_name" with "127", `messageString` gets shorter.
- You are consuming space at the beginning.

I think this should do it:

```
var messageString = "The folder #folder_name was removed from the workspace #workspace_name by #user_name"
var re = /(^|\W)#(\w+)/g, match;
var changedString = messageString;
while (match = re.exec(messageString)) {
    changedString = changedString.replace(match[0], match[1] + extra_data[match[2]]);
}
```